# Data Hog Notification

Tags: android

I just like to ask how can you know that a certain application is using too much network? I wanted to create an android application that can notify the user if it is hogging your data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [NetCounter](https://www.jaqpot.net/svn/android/netcounter/trunk/src/net/jaqpot/netcounter/service/NetCounterService.java) has done something similar.

The data usage rates are polled using

```
// Reads the values.
long rx = SysClassNet.getRxBytes(inter);
long tx = SysClassNet.getTxBytes(inter);
```

I guess your service will keep a check on the [running applications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) and the data tranfer rates.

Oh and NetCounter is GPLv3 license